# Why do we need a hold pin when we can use the ready pin in 8086 processor?

Tags: io, hardware, x86-16, dma, microprocessors

When supporting DMA operations in max mode we use ready signals to keep the microprocessor in wait state. Why can't we do the same in the min mode? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't know if [this](https://nptel.ac.in/courses/Webcourse-contents/IISc-BANG/Microprocessors%20and%20Microcontrollers/pdf/Teacher_Slides/mod1/M1L3.pdf) helps.

Comment: DMA requires more than just slowing the processor down.  The controller needs to handshake with the processor to ensure it can now drive the address and data busses by itself and start the DMA transfer.  The required request/grant bus signals are not available in mini mode.

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks guys.